# Is struct copying standard?

Tags: c++

This seems to work on my compiler but is it standard? Should I do a memcpy instead?

```
struct Foo { u32 a, b; u8 c[24]; }
class Bar {
    Foo f; 
public: 
    Bar(Foo&f):f(f){} 
};
```

Comment: yes it is standard to performing bit-wise copying

Comment: it is perfectly OK, as `Foo` is an agregate. A memcpy is implicitly performed. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4178175/what-are-aggregates-and-pods-and-how-why-are-they-special

Comment: @vsoftco: I heard of POD but never aggregate

Comment: @acidzombie24 Here is a link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4178175/what-are-aggregates-and-pods-and-how-why-are-they-special Since you don't have any explicitly declared copy ctors, a bitwise-copy is performed, so you should be safe.

Comment: @vsoftco The implicit generation of a copy constructor does not require the type to be an aggregate, and even if it is, the compiler is almost certainly not going to emit an actual call to `memcpy` or even inline `memcpy` itself; it can generate more efficient code since the size is known at compile time.

Comment: @Brian yes, but if the type is an aggregate (as it is in this case), then the default copy ctor is just a bit-wise copy. (modified my previous comment also). What I wanted to say is that in this case, the class is just an aggregate, so a default bit-wise copying ctor is generated, and everything should work just fine. Isn't this accurate?

Comment: @vsoftco I believe the term is *trivially copyable*. Aggregates are usually, but not always, trivially copyable.

Comment: @user657267, it may be, somehow I am really unable to keep track of all the nuances/exceptions of C++, and in my opinion (although I still find C++ the best language) I find that all of these nuances/interpretations are just making everyone's life harder. I truly hope for a significant simplification in the next major standard, as I fell C++ is becoming a monster, harder and harder to tame. Even this question, it seemed simple, although it took a significant effort to find out the answer to it (and I'm still not convinced I got it right).

Comment: It's worth noting that structs behave the same way as classes, except that member visibility is public by default (versus private by default in a class). All of the same rules regarding copying, assignment, etc. all apply to structs and classes equally.

Comment: @vsoftco You're never going to get simplification out of a new standard. It is extremely rare for things to get removed from programming languages. The Cobol `ALTER` verb is almost the only exception I can think of. And even if you do get a removal, compiler vendors have to support all past versions anyway.

Comment: @EJP, agree, I think the major problem is the fear of breaking legacy code. In my opinion, one has to take a step forward, and forget about legacy code and just implement a better language with a decent syntax. Right now, writing a C++ parser is almost as complicated as sending a space probe to Mars. If we'll always want backwards compatibility, then of course the new implementation will almost always be a superset, that include all previous defects.

Comment: @vsoftco I looked at the link. I know PODs are a bitwise copy and I know a memcpy will work. I just never heard of an 'aggregate' in C++ until now. The link makes it sound like all PODs are aggregates but aggregates might not be a POD? I didn't read the article linked in that link

Comment: @acidzombie24, the term "aggregate" seem to appear in `3.8` of the standard `3.8 Object lifetime [basic.life]`, without a previous definition. It is however defined in `8.5.1 Aggregates [dcl.init.aggr]`. This is according to my latest sync with the std, `N4140` from github.

Comment: @vsoftco An aggregate need not be a POD. An aggregate can be a struct with, say, an `std::string` and an `std::vector`. So, a plain bitwise copy or `memcpy` would of course not do.

Comment: @juanchopanza you're right, in that case the copy ctor of the member will take care of the copying and of course memcpy wouldn't work. I actually didn't know until now that an aggregate may contain members with a user defined constructor, thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C++11 International Standard, `struct Foo` is regarded as `POD` (Plain Old Data, refer to clause 9 spec#10), and it is `trivially copyable type`(refer to clause 3.9 spec#9). 
the bitwise-copying is normally determined by the size of the the type, for small types, it may be optimized as a simple `movl/movq` instruction. The compiler will do the job, thus you do not need `memcpy` in the constructor block of `class Bar`, since you have set the value in the initializer list `Bar(Foo&f):f(f)`.